# /undefined site error from iOS7 Safari bookmarks

Tags: javascript, php, ios7, mobile-safari

Hi I have a mobile site having the following URL http://example.com/mobile/index.html. When a user creates a bookmark of the site in iOS7 Safari & opens the bookmark from the homescreen I get the following error from my server /mobile/undefined in my application error log. Can anyone explain why this error gets thrown & how I can remove it?
Iam using PHP as my backend language & Apache Web Server.

Note: This error does not break any feature in my app but it is very annoying. Thanks.

Comment: What's the exact error, and in which log?

Comment: /mobile/undefined is the error, it is in server application log.

Comment: G can you paste the entire line of the error, or is that it? '/mobile/undefined'? Is it a 500, 502, 404?

Comment: 2013/10/07 11:53:41 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception
'CHttpException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request
"mobile/undefined" - Its a 404 obviously because I dont have a mapping for mobile/undefined, my question is why does such a request originate in the first place & how can i get rid of it?

Comment: I believe it's requesting the home screen icon. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4